# Speech Recognition on Samsung Gear S2

Tags: javascript, tizen, samsung-gear

I want to a do a sample app to test the voice recognition of samsung gear s2.

I'm looking for a sample similar to this:

[speech recognition sample](https://www.google.com/intl/es/chrome/demos/speech.html)

I'm trying to do this in a wearable project with Tizen SDK 2.3.1, but it seems that Google API for speech recognition is not supported.

When I do this in a JavaScript file:

```
if ('webkitSpeechRecognition' in window) {
```

It works on Tizen Web Simulator, but it doesn't work on the real device Samsung Gear S2.

How could I implement speech recognition on samsung gear s2, in a Tizen Web Project?